# Unable to load python packages when creating a system file in linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, systemctl

I have created a simple script to send message to AWS SQS from a python file. I have imported boto3 package and tested it locally.
Now when I am trying to create a service file and run it using it, it says unable to import boto3, even though the boto3 package is installed (I rechecked it using pip freeze | grep boto3)

Here is my code:

```
import boto3
import json
AWS_SQS_QUEUE_NAME = "XXXXXXXXX"


class SQSQueue(object):
    def __init__(self, queueName=None):
        self.resource = boto3.resource('sqs',region_name="ap-south-1")
        self.queue = self.resource.get_queue_by_name(QueueName=AWS_SQS_QUEUE_NAME)
        self.QueueName = queueName
    
    def send(self, Message={}):
        data = json.dumps(Message)
        response = self.queue.send_message(MessageBody=data)
        return response
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = SQSQueue(queueName=AWS_SQS_QUEUE_NAME)
    message = {
        "user": "XXXX",
        "timestamp": "2020-03-04 18:06:09"
    }
    
    response = q.send(Message=message)
```

My Service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Dummy Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/code/sample.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I also tried creating a bash file and calling the python file from there but it gives the same error

Error:

```
Sep 04 15:31:34 virtualhost systemd[1]: Started Access Service.
Sep 04 15:31:35 virtualhost python3[6877]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 04 15:31:35 virtualhost python3[6877]:   File "/home/ubuntu/code/sample.py", line 1, in <module>
Sep 04 15:31:35 virtualhost python3[6877]:     import boto3
Sep 04 15:31:35 virtualhost python3[6877]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'
Sep 04 15:31:35 virtualhost systemd[1]: sudoaccess.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 04 15:31:35 virtualhost systemd[1]: sudoaccess.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: What's the output from `/usr/bin/python3 -m pip list | grep boto3` ?

Comment: boto3 1.14.55, it returns this. If i am opening shell via /usr/lib/python3 and importing boto3 there, it is importing it without any errors as well

Comment: I just want to check if it's installed as a user package or globally. What's the output from this? `python3 -c 'import boto3; print(boto3.__path__)'`

Comment: ['/home/aniket/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3'] -- It returns this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you have boto3 installed as a user package, and you're running the systemd service as `root`, this is why Python only has access to system level packages.

You have 2 options:

The easy way is installing boto3 system wide, by running `python3 -m pip install boto3` as root.

Or a much cleaner way for a deployment would be create a virtualenv with only the required libraries:

```
python3 -m venv /home/ubuntu/myenv/
source /home/ubuntu/myenv/bin/activate
pip install boto3
```

And then use that virtualenv on the service definition:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/myenv/bin/python /home/ubuntu/code/sample.py
```

Comment: Thank you, I installed the package using the root user and it worked, but your solution is much more cleaner and more cleaner. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help! Yeah try to keep your "system" Python as clean as possible, with virtualenvs you can deploy several projects with different requirements and library versions on the same server.